# Unable to access my local easyphp server on internet

Tags: server, easyphp

i am running easyphp server at my local server as well as LAN 
how to access webpage from local server to internet
working at Local address 127.0.0.1/webpage
working at LAN Address 192.168.0.236:8081/webpage
i have a static ip also
plz tell me what the necessary chacges i have to do in httpd.txt

localeasyphpserveroninternet